# Can request.user be False while request.user.is_authenticated is True?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

A snippet out of Django Rest Framework:

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and is_authenticated(request.user)

def is_authenticated(user):
    if django.VERSION < (1, 10):
        return user.is_authenticated()
    return user.is_authenticated
```

Is there a practical and relevant case where my own code would return unexpected or different results from the above?

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_authenticated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If request.user isn't defined yours will error. In other words if the user isn't identified so hasn't been added to the request object.

If you're not interested in backwards compatibility I suppose you could do:

```
return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
```

Comment: So the solution is to wrap it in a try-except?

Comment: Could do but why write four lines when one will do?